# htaccess dynamic rewrite rule

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have some request parameters which I am converting to friendly URL

For example:

```
http://domain.com/members/girls/sort/last_reg/nick/ted/from/18/to/28/hfrom/150/hto/190/bbody/Athletic/
```

The parameters are dynamic so the URL could be

```
http://domain.com/members/girls/nick/ted/from/18/to/28/hfrom/150/hto/190/bbody/Athletic/
```

or

```
http://domain.com/members/men/nick/ted/to/28/hfrom/150/hto/190/bbody/Athletic/
```

The parameters are in pairs

```
parameter_name/parameter_value
```

The only thing which is constant is

```
http://domain.com/members/
```

How to transform this URL to

```
http://domain.com/filename.php?sex=men&pram1=value1&param2=value2 ......
```

or

```
http://domain.com/filename.php?sex=girls&pram1=value1&param2=value2 ......
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

## recucrsion based rule to convert 
## /members/men/n1/v1/n2/v2 to /members.php?n2=v2&n1=v1&sex=men

RewriteRule ^(members)/(girls|men)(/.*)?$ /$1/$3?sex=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^(members)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)(/.*)?$ /$1/$4?$2=$3 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^(members)/?$ /$1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is good, however I have one parameter value which do not have parameter name in the URL it is men or girls for example http://domain.com/members/men/p1/v1/p2/v2... and it has to rewrite to http://domain.com/members.php?sex=men&p1=v1&p2=v2....

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ filename.php?$1=$2&$3=$4 [L,QSA]
```